# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'

Tags: javascript

На check io решаю задачу по нахождению количества чисел в строке. Но check io ругается на  if (!isNaN(elem[j])) . Если тестить этот код в браузере то никаких ошибок нет. В чем может быть проблема?

```js
function countDigits(text) {
  var arr = text.split(" ");
  var count = 0;
  var elem = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (isNaN(arr[i])) {
      continue;
    }

    elem = arr[i].split('');

    for (j = 0; j < elem.length; j++) {
      if (!isNaN(elem[j])) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(count);
  return count;
}

console.log('Example:');
console.log(countDigits('hi 1 р2'));
```

Comment: вы проверяете сначала i-тый елемент на иснан, и если он всетаки число вы смотрите каждый символ етого как уже известно числа, и проверяете число ли ето, может на ето ругаеться ?
Плюс вы таким способом щитаете количество цифер в существующих в строке числах, судя по описанию в вопросе ето не совсем то что нужно сделать

Comment: "Плюс вы таким способом щитаете количество цифер в существующих в строке числах, судя по описанию в вопросе ето не совсем то что нужно сделать" - это нужно сделать

Comment: формально isNaN определяется как  [`isNaN ( number )`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-isnan-number) и check io судя по всему просто решил проверит типы. В браузере же это работает, потому что сам js в данном случае тип аргумента не проверяет, а просто пытается привести к числу любое переданное значение.

Comment: собственно скорее всего надо бы еще метку поменять с javascript на typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если способ решения в задаче не оговаривается, то посчитать можно с помощью регулярного выражения. Но цифр всего 10, а чисел бесконечное кол-во. То что ниже, считает кол-во чисел - как в задаче, а не цифр.

**Общее кол-во:**

```js
let str = "hi 123 р2 12p32 12";
let split = str.match(/\d+/g);
let count = split ? split.length : 0;
console.log(count);
```

**Кол-во уникальных:**

```js
let str = "hi 123 р2 12p32 12";
let split = str.match(/\d+/g);
let count = split ? split.filter((x, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(x) === i).length : 0;
console.log(count);
```

Обновил. Логичное замечание @grundy

Comment: Странно, я вообще задачу не так понял.. Я думал нужно посчитать каждую отдельную цифру, а не учитывать если они в ряд идут..

Comment: упадет если чисел не будет

Comment: @Grundy логично, обновил

Comment: зачем второй раз сплитить если у тебя уже есть результат? :)

Comment: это всё спешка и прочие оправдания)